# Python property lookup with custom __setattr__ and __slots__

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I have a class that uses `__slots__` and makes them nearly immutable by overriding `__setattr__` to always raise an error:

```
class A:
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b', '_x']

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'a', a)
        object.__setattr__(self, 'b', b)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        raise AttributeError('Immutable!')

    @property
    def x():
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(value):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_x', value)
```

Here, the "private" attribute `_x` is a place-holder for a complex operation to interact with some custom hardware.

Since `x` is a property, I expect to be able to do something like

```
 inst = A(1, 2)
 inst.x = 3
```

Instead, I see my `AttributeError` with the message `Immutable!`.

There are a number of obvious workarounds here, such as to remove the custom `__setattr__` (which I do not want to do) or to rewrite it as

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if attr != 'x':
        raise AttributeError('Immutable!')
    super().__setattr__(attr, value)
```

This seems like an awkward method that has the potential to balloon out of proportion if I start adding more properties like that.

The real issue is that I do not understand why there is no conflict between `__slots__` and the property, but there is one between `__setattr__` and the property. What is happening with the lookup order, and is there another, more elegant workaround to this problem?

Comment: NVM, I understand when reading the answer...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I would be more than happy to change any phrasing you think I should.

Comment: I think it's just too early...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The real issue is that I do not understand why there is no conflict between `__slots__` and the property, but there is one between `__setattr__` and the property.

Both `__slots__` and `property` implement attribute lookup by providing a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) for the corresponding attribute(s). The presence of `__slots__` prevents arbitrary instance attribute creation not by doing anything to `__setattr__`, but by preventing creation of a `__dict__`. `property` and other descriptors don't rely on an instance `__dict__`, so they're unaffected.

However, `__setattr__` handles *all* attribute assignment, meaning that descriptor invocation is `__setattr__`'s responsibility. If your `__setattr__` doesn't handle descriptors, descriptors won't be handled, and `property` setters won't be invoked.

> is there another, more elegant workaround to this problem?

You could explicitly allow only properties:

```
class A:
    ...
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not isinstance(getattr(type(self), name, None), property):
            raise AttributeError("Can't assign to attribute " + name)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

or you could explicitly reject assignment to slots, and delegate other attribute assignment to `super().__setattr__`:

```
class A:
    ...
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(getattr(type(self), name, None), _SlotDescriptorType):
            raise AttributeError("Can't assign to slot " + name)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

# Seems to be the same as types.MemberDescriptorType,
# but the docs don't guarantee it.
_SlotDescriptorType = type(A.a)
```

Comment: Both of these are exactly what I was looking for. I like the first one better for my particular application though.

Comment: Is there any way to set a property on an instance? I.e., is `getattr(type(self), name, None)` necessary in the first case, or is `getattr(self, name, None)` OK?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `getattr(self, ...` would get the attribute value, not the descriptor that handles the attribute. (It's technically possible for `getattr(type(self), ...` to return something other than the descriptor even when there is a descriptor, but neither `property` nor slot descriptors do that.)

Comment: And am I correct in assuming that the descriptor on `type(self)` is searched before `self.__dict__`, so even if there was a property named `x` and an item in `__dict__` named `x`, the property would be accessed in `self.x = value`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Only "data" descriptors - ones whose type implements `__set__` or `__delete__` - take priority over entries in the instance dict. Properties and slots are data descriptors (even if you don't provide a property setter or deleter), so they override the instance dict, but not all descriptors would. (Of course, if you're using slots, you probably don't even have an instance dict.)