# How to properly set a property from an implementation of __setattr__ defined outside the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I would like to define a function that returns a general implementation of `__setattr__` that makes the attributes unsettable unless they are properties (I should test for data descriptors in general, but that is for a later time). The function looks like this:

```
def make_setattr(doc='Immutable attributes'):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(getattr(type(self), name, None), property):
            super(type(self), self).__setattr__(name, value)
        raise AttributeError('Please stop trying!')
    __setattr__.__doc__ = doc
    return __setattr__
```

Here is a sample that showing the usage:

```
class A:
    __setattr__ = make_setattr()

    @property
    def x(self):
        return 1

    @x.setter
    def x(self, name):
        pass


class B(A):
    pass
```

This appears to work fine for non-property attributes:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.y = 1
AttributeError: Please stop trying!
>>> a.y
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'

>>> b = B()
>>> b.y = 1
AttributeError: Please stop trying!
>>> b.y
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'y'
```

However, it fails spectacularly for property attributes:

```
>>> a.x = 1
AttributeError: Please stop trying!
>>> b.x = 1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Setting the property on `a` appears to totally ignore the fact `x` is a property. Setting it on `b` goes into infinite recursion `super(type(self), self).__setattr__(name, value)`. Both calls act as though the result of `super(type(self), self)` is returning the wrong implementation of `__setattr__`.

I have tried to mitigate this by removing the arguments to `super`: `super().__setattr__(name, value)`, but both `a.x = 1` and `b.x = 1` raise

```
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
```

How do I find and call the correct parent implementation of `__setattr__` in my externally defined method? I would like to avoid explicitly calling `object.__setattr__` if at all possible in this case.

Comment: Never pass `type(self)` to `super`.

Comment: That sounds like good advice, but I'd love to know why and how to work around it properly.

Comment: I'm not sure calling `__setattr__` is what you want to call -- catch: yes, call: I'm not so sure.  You might consider calling the descriptor's `__set__` method instead.

Comment: @jedwards. That makes a lot of sense. Could you write that up as an answer please?

Comment: Calling `__set__` would work too, and it would remove the need to know about the class. The [code this was probably based on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101056/python-property-lookup-with-custom-setattr-and-slots/46101204#46101204) defined `__setattr__` inside the class, so it could just use `super().__setattr__`.

Comment: @user2357112. You got the reference just right :) I forgot to put in a link myself, but the code in the linked question is actually based on this concept, not the other way around.

Comment: Calling `__set__` explicitly does mean you won't get the effects of any other superclass `__setattr__` overrides, though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Rawing's answer (+1) nail's what I was suggesting, otherwise I would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First bug: you `raise AttributeError('Please stop trying!')` no matter what, even when you actually do set the attribute.

Second bug: passing `type(self)` to `super` is wrong, as it breaks when the class is subclassed and `type(self)` is a different type from what you expected.

You can't use 0-argument `super` because the `__class__` cell kludge it relies on is only triggered for function definitions lexically nested inside the class definition. You'll have to make your `__setattr__` aware of the class explicitly, which is difficult when the class hasn't even been created yet.

One option would be to call `make_setattr` after the class definition and have it take the class as an argument, or make `make_setattr` a class decorator, but personally, I'd probably just `def __setattr__` inside the class definition and drop `make_setattr`.

Comment: Adding the return in the test code definitely makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: The reason for having `make_setattr` is that it does a whole bunch of additional configuration that gets reused over and over in my project. Doesn't seem like a good idea to copy and paste at that point.

Comment: I will just add the class as a mandatory argument to `make_setattr`. Not any more of a problem than passing it into `super` anyway.

Comment: Can you think of a way to get the base class from the method itself? For example, would I be able to hack something like `getattr(self, '__setattr__').__class__`?

Comment: > that it does a whole bunch of additional configuration that gets reused over and over in my project < Then you can define `__setattr__` which just calls your function with shared code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Sort of, but there'd be weird edge cases. You could try searching the MRO for a `__setattr__` function that `is` the same object as the one you're defining: `klass = next(klass for klass in type(self).__mro__ if klass.__dict__.get('__setattr__') is __setattr__)`. However, the results could be strange if the same `__setattr__` function ends up in two class dicts.

Comment: @warvariuc. That is definitely an option. At this point I want to get `make_setattr` to work properly so I can better understand how the machinery works.

Comment: @user2357112. I realize this is getting a bit out of scope, but what would be the nature of the edge cases you referred to? Also, why would it be weird if the same method appeared in multiple dicts? Only the first one in MRO would ever actually pop up.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The weird edge cases would be quite similar to the RecursionError you already saw: the `__setattr__` method would find itself over and over instead of continuing on to the next implementation.

Comment: @user2357112. I will try to trigger some of them. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: FInal result: I made `make_setattr` into a class-level annotation since that is the simplest way to know what the class is.

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix is to explicitly call the property's setter function instead of using `super(...).__setattr__`:

```
def make_setattr(doc='Immutable attributes'):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        prop = getattr(type(self), name, None)
        if isinstance(prop, property):
            prop.__set__(self, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Please stop trying!')
    __setattr__.__doc__ = doc
    return __setattr__
```

Comment: This has the same limitation as calling `object.__setattr__`, in that it won't pick up any other superclass overrides of `__setattr__`.

Comment: This is a good approach and I will consider it. However, as @user2357112 pointed out, you don't get any of the additional processing that the parent `__setattr__` may be doing.

Comment: I think that I'll make this my fallback if the correct starting point form MRO can not be determined in other ways.